# What is the alternative for deprecated com.apple.eawt.ApplicationListener

Tags: java, macos, osx-lion

ApplicationListener class in Apple's Java is deprecated. What is the alternative?

package: com.apple.eawt

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?  Why use OS specific classes in an X-platform language?

Comment: This is a MacOS application. I need the classes for better integration with Mac OS.

Comment: I did a quick check when you first mentioned it and it seems Java Web Start can do at least some of what the `ApplicationListener` can achieve.  Further, JWS can do it X-plat.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Better integration in macOS is reason enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please migrate to using the com.apple.eawt.Application.set*Handler() APIs if you want to hook into Open, Preferences, About, Quit menu items / events.

From https://web.archive.org/web/20141020092159/http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2012/Jan/msg00101.html

The full response is

> As the deprecator of these APIs, I think I'm qualified to answer this:
>
> Please migrate to using the com.apple.eawt.Application.set*Handler()
> APIs if you want to hook into Open, Preferences, About, Quit menu
> items / events. The full JavaDocs are in the appledocs.jar in the Java
> Developer Package's JDK at
> <developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Java Developer>, as
> well as a somewhat staler copy at
> [ ... broken link ...].
>
> Most people usually just want to implement the setQuitHandler() or use
> setQuitStrategy(), and maybe want setPreferencesHandler(). The old
> style ApplicationListener was a terrible interface, because it cross
> cut too many disparate concepts and forced an application to listen to
> all of them, and allowed multiple listeners to be notified about
> things that should only be handled by a single agent.
>
> Regards, Mike Swingler Java Engineering

Comment: Here's an archived [http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2012/Jan/msg00101.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20141020092159/http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2012/Jan/msg00101.html)