# Java Applet won't launch under macOS

Tags: java, macos, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I'm attempting to start a Java applet under macOS with `java -jar HuffmanShannonFano.jar` and get this error message:

```
jakob@Jakobs-MacBook-Air ~ % java -jar /Users/jakob/Downloads/Hufmann\ Shannon-Fano/HuffmanShannonFano.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener
    at de.tillwiebke.util.MacIntegration.integrate(MacIntegration.java:42)
    at HuffmanShannonFano.main(HuffmanShannonFano.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apple.eawt.ApplicationListener
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 2 more
```

Under [Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSMIK.jpg) the Applet launches just fine. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

That class, now obsolete, was the mechanism by which a Java app could integrate into macOS. Specifically, to hook into Open, Preferences, About, Quit menu items / events.

That class was deprecated and then eventually removed from the modern versions of Java.

If you have the source code, you can replace those calls with calls to `com.apple.eawt.Application.set*Handler()` APIs.

See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090946/642706) on Question [*What is the alternative for deprecated com.apple.eawt.ApplicationListener*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9239287/642706).

Comment: I don’t have the source code. I got it working otherwise tho. I use Azul Java as the standard java on my machine because it’s native to Apple Silicon. Since I used Open JDK on Linux to run it I tried it with Open JDK under macOS. It has to run through Rosetta but it works now